# Talmud Torah synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Does anyone think (as I do) that Talmud Torah should be a synonym for the [torah-study](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-study) tag? Right now Talmud Torah doesn't redirect to anything and would have been a new tag, had I not searched and found the Torah-study tag.

Comment: Incidentally, how do you more experienced users pull the tag into the body of a question/answer?

Comment: Edited, but the syntax is `[tag:torah-study]`

Comment: @HodofHod, thanks.

Comment: Completed by msh210.

Comment: Of course, there's *some* ambiguity, because of [the other meaning of "talmud Torah"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud_Torah), but I don't think that's much of a concern at all, especially inasmuch as we're unlikely to get many questions about talmud Torahs.

Comment: @msh210, I think we've had one - or possibly an answer that referenced one. But maybe I've seen/heard that elsewhere.

Comment: (Technically, "talmud torah" means teaching Torah, so it is slightly different)

Answer (score 2):

[filler]

msh210 has merged these tags. Thanks msh210!

[more filler]